# Spring Boot Controller does not recognize Path Variable as optional

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, fetch-api

Using Spring Boot, I have implemented a RestController like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/student/img")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ProfilePictureController {

    @GetMapping( "/{studentId}")
    public void getProfilePicture(@PathVariable(required = false) Long studentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        Optional<ProfilePicture> profilePicture;
        if (studentId != null) {
            profilePicture= studentService.getProfilePictureByStudentId(studentId);
        } else {
            profilePicture= studentService.getProfilePicture(1L);
        }
        if (profilePicture.isPresent()) {
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(profilePicture.get().getImage());
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

My ProfilePicture-class contains a variable "image", which is of type byte[]. I am trying to retrieve this variable.

Anyways, the issue is that my controller does not seem to treat my PathVariable as optional. If I use the fetch-API to send a GET request with the following URL:

`const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/student/img/"`,

I am getting an error:

`'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "img"`.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only define the resource `/api/v1/student/img/{studentId}` but NOT the resource `/api/v1/student/img/`.

So if you just call `/api/v1/student/img/` as you mentioned , it should return you 404 Not Found but not the following error that you mentioned :

> 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception
> is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "img".

I believe you are actually calling `/api/v1/student/img/img` instead. As `img` is not a Long and hence the error.

If you just want to call `/api/v1/student/img/` without any studentId , you should define another resource for it (see below). Technically , they are different resources.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/student/img")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ProfilePictureController {

    @GetMapping( "/{studentId}")
    public void getProfilePicture(@PathVariable(required = false) Long studentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    }


    @GetMapping
    public void getProfilePicture(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
   
    }

  }
```

Or defining two resource paths on the `@GetMapping` with `Optional` on the paramater :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/student/img")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ProfilePictureController {

    @GetMapping( {"/", "/{studentId}"})
    public void getProfilePicture(@PathVariable(required = false) Optional<Long> studentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    }
  }
```

Comment: ah thx, man! I actually thought adding the `@RequestMapping("/api/v1/student/img")` annotation to my controller-class would be setting this as a resource to all mappings and then any additional mappings, e.g. `@GetMapping("/{studentId}")` would just be added. But it seems you are right, I have to add the extra slash. Thx a lot!

Comment: Using `required = false` and `Optional` at the same time is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`/api/v1/student/img/` doesn't match `/api/v1/student/img/{studentId}`. So your mapping will not work.

In addition to other anwser, In my opinion the best way to handle this is to add another mapping to the same method.

```
@GetMapping( {"/","/{studentId}"})
    public void getProfilePicture(@PathVariable(required = false) Long studentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws
        IOException {

    }
```

Find out more here https://medium.com/latesttechupdates/define-spring-optional-path-variables-1188fadfebde

Answer (score 0):

You can't have optional path variables, but you can have two controller methods which call the same service code:
**but**

If you are using Java 8 and above and Spring 4.1 and above you can use java.util.Optional which is supported in @RequestParam, @PathVariable, @RequestHeader and @MatrixVariable in Spring MVC

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/student/img")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ProfilePictureController {

    @GetMapping( "/{studentId}")
    public void getProfilePicture(@PathVariable Optional<Long> type studentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        Optional<ProfilePicture> profilePicture;
        if (studentId.isPresent()) {
            profilePicture= studentService.getProfilePictureByStudentId(studentId.get());
        } else {
            profilePicture= studentService.getProfilePicture(1L);
        }
        if (profilePicture.isPresent()) {
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(profilePicture.get().getImage());
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Here you can find some examples ==> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable

```
@GetMapping( {"/","/{studentId}"})
    public void getProfilePicture(@PathVariable Long studentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws
        IOException {

        Optional<ProfilePicture> profilePicture;
        if (studentId != null) {
            profilePicture= studentService.getProfilePictureByStudentId(studentId);
        } else {
            profilePicture= studentService.getProfilePicture(1L);
        }
        if (profilePicture.isPresent()) {
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(profilePicture.get().getImage());
            outputStream.close();
        }

    }
```